# how to obfuscate personal informations maintaining data semantic structure (Italian GDPR law)

Tags: encryption, obfuscation, google-cloud-dlp

as I imagine many of you have already done, I'm facing the problem of obfuscating the personal sensitive data of my databases for test operations.
In fact, it happens that to perform tests or verify malfunctions, we make a copy of the production database in the test environment.

This implies, however, that we carry all the personal and sensitive data of all customers.

We thought to encrypt the data but the result is that, if I have to work directly on the database or I don't have a transcoding layer, the encrypted data are useless.

So I was looking for some software that could transform the data, thus losing the original data, but that could maintain its original semantic structure.

Example:
John Doe -> Frek Rao
01/02/1987 -> 12/03/1986

In this way I can keep the data structure without having the original data.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to leverage Google's Data Loss Prevention technology.  Here is a link to the primary web page:

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/

This can detect and redact/modify/mask your sensitive data.  You have a variety of identification technologies and a rich set of replacement technologies.

I am familiar with the Google product, but there appears to be others.  Generically, what you appear to be looking for is "[data loss prevention](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/data-loss-prevention-DLP)" and searching on that phrase may show up other solutions.

Comment: Some targeted documentation that you might like, https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data and https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/transformations-reference. ReplaceWithInfoType is great for cases like this, but there are a number of transformations that would achieve your goal.